# Display bit pattern of double as hex?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, double, type-punning

I am trying to use `printf` in order to print the binary representation of a double onto the console. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a = 4.75;
    unsigned long long b = *(unsigned long long *) &a;
    printf("Double a = %f (0x%x)" a, b);
}
```

I also tried changing it from a long long to a long instead. Here is the result that I get from doing this in gcc linux:

```
Double a = 4.750000 (0x0)
```

I'm pretty sure since my system is little endian that it is only grabbing the first 32 bits which are all zeroes. However, I'm not sure how to fix this.

I thought it might have been because long is 64 bit in linux but after testing that I got the same result again. Maybe I'm printing it incorrectly? Not sure, let me know and thanks for your time.

Comment: Does not `*(unsigned long long *) &a;` violate strict aliasing?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, see [What is strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228315/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks for the confirmation sir, that was more of a rhetorical q. :)

Comment: `printf("Double a = %f (0x%llx)", a, b);`

Comment: @SouravGhosh the information was for the general audience who may not understand ;-)

Comment: I really don't see how this is _not_ a dupe of the strict aliasing question. If we are to keep it open, the question needs to be narrowed down to C or C++. Currently it is too broad. It would be helpful if high rep users with gold badges did an effort in moderating the cross-posting aspect of C and C++ tags _before_ writing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two issues, the simple one is that you are using the wrong format specifier `%llx` is the correct specifier for *unsigned long long*. Both clang and gcc provide a warning for this using `-Wall`, [see it live](https://godbolt.org/z/Yfmsd2).

The second issue is that you are violating the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228315/1708801) here:

```
unsigned long long b = *(unsigned long long *) &a;
```

the correct way to type-pun (in both C and C++) is to use memcpy ([see it working live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7y0RHfA6n6XwAR8y)):

```
std::memcpy( &b, &a, sizeof(double));
```

At the strict aliasing link above notes in C++20 we should get `bit_cast` which will simplify type-punning e.g.:

```
b = bit_cast<unsigned long long>(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

In C, code like

```
unsigned long long b = *(unsigned long long *) &a;
```

is illegal as it violates a rule called strict aliasing about pointers of one type referencing objects of a different type.

However, there is on exception: **a char pointer may alias any object**

So using char pointer, you can do something like this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a = 4.75;
    unsigned char* p;

    // Method 1 - direct memory read
    p = (unsigned char*)&a;
    for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof(double); ++i)
    {
        printf("%02x ", *p);
        ++p;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Method 2 - reversed memory read
    size_t i = sizeof(double);
    p = (unsigned char*)&a + i - 1;
    do
    {
        printf("%02x ", *p);
        --p;
        --i;
    } while(i > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 13 40 
40 13 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The two methods prints with different endianness.

If you don't like pointers, you can as an alternative use a union. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    union
    {
        double a;
        char c[sizeof(double)];
    } d;
    d.a = 4.75;

    for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof(double); ++i)
    {
        printf("%02x ", d.c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    size_t i = sizeof(double);
    do
    {
        --i;
        printf("%02x ", d.c[i]);
    }
    while (i > 0);
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 13 40 
40 13 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: A minor addition: The type-punning is standard conform in C11 but not allowed in C++. You dedicated your answer to C. Hopefully, OP did notice this.

Answer (score 2):

In C++:

```
double a = 4.75;
char tmp[sizeof(double)];
memcpy(tmp, &a, sizeof(double));
... // print individual bytes as hex
```

Alternatively:

```
double a = 4.75;
unsigned char* tmp = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++)
  ... // print *(tmp + i) as hex
```